# not working loader complete handler if url has only http://abc.com

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using flash builder 4.5.

I used loader and urlrequest class to download/embed image to find out width and height. It works fine if the url is http(s)://www.abc.com/one.png. But if i use same technique to download/embed dropbox media (http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/****/Photos/Sample%20Album/Costa%20Rican%20Frog.jpg) using complete handler, doesn;t fire it.

I was thinking that problem is because www is not in url.

Please tel me if anyone has experiance.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it has `www` or not. Technically `www` is a subdomain, just like `dl`, and it's a valid `URL`. It must be a security problem. Maybe you can solve it using a php proxy.

Comment: I'm getting url from java server. http://www.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/**/Photos/Sample%20Album/Costa%20Rican%20Frog.jpg will not work if we check in browser. I did that testing... so in that case loader-complete handler is not at all triggering. I agree with your point of security. Let me check it what Jono said.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a security sandbox issue. See here for a similar issue and resolution - http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?357992-www-works-without-www-doesn-t-problem-with-URLRequest#post_2587691

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me try the ans that you provided here.